# can't use the debugger with elm-reactor

Tags: debugging, elm

I'm trying to use the [Debugger](http://debug.elm-lang.org/) with elm-reactor but I get this error:

```
`Debug` does not expose `watch`.
```

I'm importing the **Debug** package:

```
import Debug
```

as per the [mouse example](http://debug.elm-lang.org/edit/Stamps.elm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of `0.17.0` release, [**Debug**](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Debug) package no longer exposes `watch` function.

`Debug.watch` only makes sense in the context of [Time-Travel Debugging](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Debug#time-travel-debugging), which is not available in `0.17.0` release.

The example you are referring to is written using Elm `0.16.0`, any examples using `Signal` package are not relevant anymore.

See more details on the latest release in the official blog post from Evan: [A Farewell to FRP](http://elm-lang.org/blog/farewell-to-frp)

Comment: Thank you, what a pity that we don't have Time-Travel Debugging anymore. Hope they will bring it back soon!

Comment: @pietro909 Happy to help! In fact, there is a community-made Time-Travel Debugger [https://github.com/jinjor/elm-time-travel](https://github.com/jinjor/elm-time-travel), but the official version will be available in the next releases, according to [**Evan's comment**](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-reactor/issues/186) on the matter.

Answer (score 5):

[`watch` was removed from Debug](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/commit/c687ef7e53bf0101f9c78b87a33636548ba8e5da) prior to the release of 0.17.

[Here is a discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/elm-dev/AhZPhwP1CmM) about the decision which oscillates between moving `watch` and `watchSummary` to a new `Reactor` module (since they were only useful within elm-reactor), or replacing them altogether with `log` and `logSummary`. Neither of these resolutions have happened as of 0.17, so we are left without them for now.